# Checking Metatype, obtained as an argument

Tags: swift, function

Classes Vc1 and Vc2  are subclasses of UIViewController:

```
class Vc1: UIViewController { .... }
class Vc2: UIViewController { .... }
```

The following function checks sender type, obtained as an argument:

```
func onVCComplete(senderType: UIViewController.Type, details: Any) {

    switch senderType {
        case Vc1.self: ...            
        case Vc2.self: ...
        default: break
    }
}
```

which gives compilation error: `Expression pattern of type 'Vc1.Type' cannot match values of type 'UIViewController.Type'`.

Tried `Any.Type` instead of `UIController.Type` - same error.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: It's just another type, so that's why you get an error. You can send UIViewController to your function and check if casting it to a specific subclass succeed.

Comment: Seems strange but if you use `if senderType == Vc1.self {}`, it doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess maybe your intention is to instantiate a vc, and check its actually type and do some extra work on it...If so, why not just create the object and then check its type?

```
import UIKit

class Vc1: UIViewController {}

class Vc2: UIViewController {}

func onVCComplete<T: UIViewController>(senderType: T.Type, details: Any) {

    let vc = senderType.init()

    switch vc {
    case is Vc1:
        print("do something with Vc1")
    case is Vc2:
        print("do something with Vc2")
    default:
        print("some other vcs")
    }
}

onVCComplete(senderType: Vc1.self, details: "Whatever")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think initializing ViewController just for check its type is not good.

Comment: But the point is checking via _MetaType_ not via _initialising_

Answer (score -2):

Check below sample to check. It may help you.

```
class A {

}

class B : A {

}

class C : A {

}

func onVCComplete(senderType: A, details: Any) {

    if senderType is B {
        print("B")
    }
    if senderType is C {
         print("C")
    }
}

onVCComplete(senderType: C(), details: "A")
```

It will print "C"